# queuering GCD with 2 blocks

Tags: ios, multithreading, queue, dispatch

I want create queue in that first block will run in background, then it finished I want run second block in main thread

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
 // block 1

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

  // block 2
      });
    });
```

How to add queue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have, i.e. nested GCD calls, should work fine. It should call the main thread only when the code *above* the GCD call to the main thread is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a queue like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.queue", 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();


dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    // block 1

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        printf("first block\n");
    });

    // block 2

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        printf("second block\n");
    });

});

dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    printf("all tasks are finished!\n");
});


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // your code on main thread to update UI
    printf("main thread\n");

});
```

Comment: Are you sure that it do not need end with }); }); ?

Comment: I double checked and it's working OK like that. Thanks.